# How to get logcat for an Android app on BlackBerry 10 devices

Tags: eclipse, blackberry, blackberry-10, blackberry-android, momentics

I was only able to find logcat for native apps.

When I connected to the device with Momentics and used the target file navigator I did not find the logcat file for the Android app I am testing.

Is there any other option apart from Momentics?

I use the Eclipse IDE for Android. I have installed BB ADT because it's their option as the device explorer and DDMB do not identify BlackBerry 10 devices.

Comment: Seems as if BB10 is dead... even on SO.

Answer (score 1):

This blog post on the BB developers site may help...
http://devblog.blackberry.com/2013/11/pull-android-logs-from-your-blackberry/